# How to know the page from which a product is added to the cart? - WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to know, on the wc report page (or somewhere else), the page from which a product is added to the cart.

I'm working at an online food market which has a recipe blog, on each recipe page there is a section featuring the products used on the recipe.

We're developing an affiliate program in which each recipe author will get paid for each product a customer adds from one of his/her recipe; for such reason it's imperative for us to know the page from which each product is added to the cart.

Any idea about how to get this done?
I appreciate the help, and I'll give further details if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :

In this display only page/post URL and page/post ID. You need to store page ID/URL and can get from database.

**NOTE :**  This is code working only in details page.

```
function custom_to_cart_item( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    $page_url = wp_get_referer();
    $page_id = url_to_postid( $page_url );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'custom_to_cart_item', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Milan. I think it can be achieved using the `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` filter. I checked [this post](https://iconicwp.com/blog/add-custom-cart-item-data-woocommerce/) post on iconic giving a detailed explanation on how to it

Comment: wp_get_referer() is the same as the current request URL please read document - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_referer/ and url_to_postid is check permalink please read document - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it done, here is the code I used:

```
// To create a new product meta data with the page from which the product is added:

function custom_to_cart_item( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
$page_url = wp_get_referer();
$page_id = url_to_postid( $page_url );
$cart_item_data['page-of-addition'] =  $page_id;

return $cart_item_data;}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'custom_to_cart_item', 10, 3 );
```

In the case you want to display such value un the order page:

```
function add_addition_page_to_order_items( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
if ( empty( $values['page-of-addition'] ) ) {
    return;
}

$item->add_meta_data( __( 'Page of addition', 'wpi18n' ), $values['page-of-addition'] );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_addition_page_to_order_items', 10, 4 );
```

Thanks a lot @Milan Hirpara. I also complemented the code with some of what's shared on [iconic](https://iconicwp.com/blog/add-custom-cart-item-data-woocommerce/#comment-1238)